# Finding $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} $ if $ F(cx - az, cy-bz) = 0 $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> If it is given that $ F(cx - az, cy-bz) = 0 $, then find $ \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

How do I go about doing this? I don't really understand which variables are independent and which aren't.

I'm new to partial derivatives. I know chain rule though. Some hints?

---

As per Blah's answer, here's what I've done:

$$ F_x = F_u (c - az_x) + F_v(-bz_x) = 0 $$
$$ F_y = F_u (- az_y) + F_v(c -bz_y) = 0 $$
(The "$=0$" is there because $F$ is constant (zero) for all values of $x$ and $y$)

So, by doing some algebra, I get $z_x = \dfrac{cF_u} { bF_v + aF_u }$ and something similar for $z_y$.

But the above contains $F_u$ and $F_v$. How do I get rid of those?

Comment: Did you try differentiating?

Comment: I don't really know how to differentiate this, and with respect to what. My problem is, if I try differentiating the function $F$ wrt $x$, I don't know what expression to right.

Comment: The chain rule, as I know, is : "If $F = F(u,v)$ and $u = u(x,y)$ and $v = v(x,y)$ and $x, y$ are independent, then $F_x = F_u\cdot u_x + F_v\cdot v_x$". But over here, I don't really understand who's independent and who's not.

Comment: Assume $x$ and $y$ are independent and $z$ is a function of them. You said you "don't know how to differentiate this," but really you *do* know how to differentiate it, you've just been too worried to actually do it!

Comment: But won't it be a problem if $u = cx - az$ and $v = cy - bz$ both depend upon $z$ which again depends upon $x, y$?

Comment: Nvm....Let me see.

Comment: The function $(x,y)\to z(x,y)$ *depends* of $F$. Isn't reasonable expecting get rid of it. And is *Blas*. :-)

Comment: Haha, I actually meant Blah. I used your idea too (of having $F_x = 0$) though did not explicitly mention your name. Sorry about that! And I got this question from a friend. He wasn't very sure of the question. His question was to prove that $a\dfrac{ \partial z } {\partial x} = b \dfrac{\partial z} {\partial y} = c$. But because he wasn't really sure of the question, I worded it differently over here. And anyway, will I still have $F_u$ and $F_v$ in the final expression? Even if it is not possible to get rid of $F$, I think we should be able to get rid of $u$ and $v$...

Comment: $a\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=b\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=c$ does not follow from $F(cx-az,cy-bz)=0$. Take $F(u,v)=u+v$ for instance. Why do you think we should be able to get rid of $F_u$ and $F_v$? Do you have any evidence whatsoever? There's a good possibility there are things you aren't telling us, or else you've otherwise incorrectly communicated the question to us.

Comment: I know that it doesn't follow from the given question. I considered the same example $F(u,v) = u+v$ and it didn't work out. That is why I never asked to prove it. And with regards to getting rid of $F_u$ and $F_v$, I think we must be able to do something regarding that since $u$ and $v$ aren't given in the question. What I meant by getting rid of $u$ and $v$ was to get the final answer in terms of only the given symbols - $F, x, y, z, a, b, c$. Sorry for the miscommunication!

Answer (score 3):

The equation
$$F(cx - az, cy-bz) = 0$$
defines implicitly a function $(x,y)\mapsto z(x,y)$ *under reasonable hypothesis* (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).
Applying the chain rule to
$$\pmatrix{x\cr y}\longmapsto \pmatrix{cx-az(x,y)\cr cy-bz(x,y)}\longmapsto F(cx - az(x,y), cy-bz(x,y))$$
and using that $F(cx - az(x,y), cy-bz(x,y))=0$ forall $(x,y)$ you will obtain a system of two equations with two unknowns $\partial z/\partial x$ and $\partial z/\partial y$.

Answer (score 1):

*How do I go about doing this?*

Introduce new functions (in addition zu $z=z(x,y)$)
$$
u(x,y)=cx-az(x,y) \qquad v(x,y)=cy-bz(x,y)
$$
and compute
$$
u_x=c-az_x \qquad u_y=-az_y \qquad v_x=-bz_x \qquad v_y=c-bz_y
$$
Now use the chain rule to write $z_x,z_y$ in in terms of the partial derivatives of $F$

Comment: So I'll be getting $z_x$ and $z_y$ in terms of partial derivatives of $F$? I mean, is there any way to get rid of $F$ from the answer? (Sorry, missed typing that)

Comment: I'll update my question to show what I've done.